# How do I format doc.writeln without using quotation marks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I receive an error in the console when I want to write a html doc with this syntax:

```
doc.writeln ("  $e.html($(e).html().split(text).join('<span class='matching'>' + text + '</span>'));");
```

the error appear here:

```
join('<span class='matching'>'
```

exactly:

```
'<span class='
```

I can't put double quotation marks `""` but only single quotes `''` on `"matching"`.
How can I write the code to overcome this error?

Comment: Use the backslash to escape quotes within quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes that are inside other quotes. You also have to double the backslashes so that the backslashes will be treated literally inside the double quotes.

```
doc.writeln ("  $e.html($(e).html().split(text).join('<span class=\\'matching\\'>' + text + '</span>'));");
```